# Generate 30 second preview of mp3

Tags: javascript, php, mp3

i want to generate a 30 sec preview from the mp3 file using custom php script. the script will automatically trip the clip to 30 sec preview and after that the audio file will stop automatically.
moreover, i am not sure of any libraries on the system so please share step by step process with me.

Comment: What database program? You've tagged two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no good idea but:

```
SELECT * FROM users where (email = 'mohsin@ac.com' OR username = 'mosin')
and password = 'sdssd'
```

I think you must authenticate only with username, you can decide to use email field as username.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i_want_to_login_by_email = true;
$field = 'username';
if( $i_want_to_login_by_email )
{
 $field = 'email';
}

$qry =<<<Rohit
SELECT * FROM users where {$field} = "{$value}"  and password = 'sdssd'
Rohit;
```